# QDial disabling full tour

Tags: python, qt, slider, pyqt, limit

My question is about `QDial`. It can make the full tour around. When the value is 0 it jumps to 100 and if the value is 100 and you turn it a little more it passes to 0 suddenly.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
setWrapping(False)
```

also see [QDial reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdial.html#wrapping-prop).

Answer (score 1):

Actually @Trilarion , setWrapping to false does not fix his problem.
The Dial still jumps from end to beginning and vice-versa. This is not cool in some applications.

The only solution, I believe, is to hardly not allowing the Dial to do this in a slot. For example, in value changed. Considering you stored the previous value, you can prevent the user from jumping with the dial around by setting the value again.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setWrapping(True)
```

and not False as suggest Trilarion